# Ошибка LEFT JOIN laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
$this->orderBy('post_id','desc')
        ->join('users','posts.post_author','=','users.id')
        ->join('categories','posts.post_category','=','categories.category_id')
        ->paginate($pnum)
```

Вот так делаю join. При подключение join'a категорий появляется только одна запись из базы, без join'a категорий появляется две (как и должно)

Вот так выглядит posts:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит category:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. обычные джоин из pma проходит отлично

Answer (score 1):

Заменил join на leftJoin. Помогло :)